# UIButton flickers when using setBackgroundImage in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I am displaying a `UIButton` in a `viewcontroller` which is contained within a `navigationcontroller`. 
The problem is that when the view appears using push transition the button flickers.

I have already looked into existing solutions on SO but none of them seemed to work.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
//call to super

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NormalImage"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedImage"]  forState:forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SelectedImage"]  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

}
```

1)I tried using setImage instead , it does not work. Infact it does not show image at all.
2)disabling animation works in `viewdidload` (and enable in `viewDidAppear` ) but it also disabled navigation controller animation. 
`[UIViews setAnimationsDisabled];`

Comment: can you show the screenshot please ?

Comment: also try to put those code in `viewDidAppear:`

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo screenshot won't help because the transition between two images is for a very short period of time. I tried to put the code in viewDidAppear but it doesn't look good while changing image in viewDidappear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning a different background image to your button through Interface Builder ?.
What could be happening here is that your button has a different set of images assigned in Interface Builder and you are changing the backgrounds after the view has been loaded and probably already displayed,  so you see the flicker . 
I'd suggest doing your configuration of your button directly in your xib file if possible.